# In RoR, if I say that A has_one B, is it mandatory that A has one B?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, has-one

I need to setup a relationship so that A has one B, but there will be some entries where A doesn't have a B. Is this possible? If not, how can this be done?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. By default A doesn't have to have a B unless you add code to enforce it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that there is a B by adding `validates_presence_of :b` in class A

Comment: i think you mean "enforce" instead of "check"?